# Is it possible to allocate dynamic memory in bits?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, dynamic, linux-kernel

Can we allocate dynamic memory in bits? I know `malloc()` requires size of memory in bytes. Can we write a kernel module that allocates memory in bits? and this module should be called by user program to allocate memory in bits.If you guys say yes, I'll start working on it.

Comment: `ptr = malloc((numBits + 7) / 8);`

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The smallest addressable unit is the byte. The overhead in managing sub-byte addressing will more than waste any 'benefit' you might realise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you cannot allocate a bit (not even a byte in modern systems) because you can't address it. A memory address always gives data with the width of the data-bus (eg.64Bit).

If you want to emulate bitwise allocation @godel9 is right. I'd prefer

```
ptr = malloc((numbits % 8) + 1).
```

Comment: Your formula is wrong - it will never allocate more than 8 bytes

Answer (score 5):

If you need to allocate enough memory to store `numBits` bits, you can just divide `numBits` by 8, round up, and call `malloc` with that number of bytes. You may have some extra bits at the end, but that shouldn't be a problem:

```
void *allocBits(size_t numBits) {
    return malloc((numBits + 7) / 8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no reason for writing this module, because there is no any hardware way to allocate single bit in a memory which is divided into 32-bit areas in most cases. Even on 8-bit architectures the smallest amount of a memory is one byte and there is no way for addressing single bit in a hardware way (except special cases like ARM's bit-banding).